# Python yfinance module not connecting to server?

Tags: python, yfinance

I'm new to yfinance and am just trying to write a code in which you input a stock ticker and output its current price.

This is all I've done so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as data
import numpy as np
import seaborn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import googlefinance as gf
import yfinance as yf
from yahoo_finance import Share

msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")

# get all stock info
print(msft.info)
```

But currently I just get this as a result:

```
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v6/finance/quoteSummary/MSFT?modules=financialData&modules=quoteType&modules=defaultKeyStatistics&modules=assetProfile&modules=summaryDetail&ssl=true
```

I've tried restarting my computer and everything. Nothing changes, it still won't produce the expected output.

Comment: When I attempt to access the URL that your YFinance call is attempting to reach (https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v6/finance/quoteSummary/MSFT?modules=financialData&modules=quoteType&modules=defaultKeyStatistics&modules=assetProfile&modules=summaryDetail&ssl=true) in the browser, I get an error message stating 


"Will be right back...
Thank you for your patience.

Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue."

It is likely a backend issue with Yahoo. I tried running your script once again and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are encountering is due to the fact that the package you are using, `yahoo_finance`, is outdated and no longer supported.

To get the current price of a stock using the `yfinance` package, you can modify your code as follows:

```py
import yfinance as yf

# Input the stock ticker
ticker = input("Enter the stock ticker symbol: ")

# Create a Ticker object
stock = yf.Ticker(ticker)

# Get the current price
current_price = stock.history().tail(1)['Close'][0]

# Print the current price
print("Current price of", ticker, "is:", current_price)
```

This code will prompt you to enter the stock ticker symbol and will then output its current price.

Comment: Tysm . I was basing my original program off these docs here: https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/. Do you know if these yfinance docs are still accurate or are there better ones out there?